# parsing data from selenium to beautiful soup using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, lxml

I get the error

```
FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do 
you need to install a parser library?
```

My imports are...

```
import mechanize
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml
```

My code is ...

(driver.page_source prints correctly on its own with a print statement but won't parse into beautifulsoup)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url2)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(100000, 200000)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5) # wait to load
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
import lxml
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print soup
```

The Line it doesn't like is...

```
    FeatureNotFound                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-62919c26be91> in <module>()
     73 driver.quit()
     74 from lxml import etree
---> 75 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml'
```

Comment: Try `pip install lxml`

Comment: Thanks however, I've done that, and when I tried again I get... requirement already satisfied, I am running ipython from c/python27/scripts and lxml is by default installed to c/python27/lib/site-packages by the chris gohlke binary for windows.

Comment: i'm not partial to using selenium if that helps, but I need to figure out how to get ipython to recognise my pyqt4 installation first which is also in... c/python27/lib/site-packages. I'd like to use pyWebkit apparently it's much faster. but i will go with whatever I can get to work at the moment. Thanks for your suggestion.